# How do I import data from csv file as a List of different data types in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a .csv file containing a column of values of different data types (Int, float, Bool and String) - 
The column reads as -

### Values

```
10
12.5
True
Hello
```

When i import the values in a list using Pandas, all the values are imported in String format. Below is my code and output -

```
import pandas as pd
Import_CSV = pd.read_csv('Parameters.csv', header=0)
Parameters = Import_CSV.values.T[0].tolist()
print(Parameters)
```

the output is `['10', '12.5', 'True', 'Hello']`
Is there any way to import the values as it is? I mean 10 as int, 12.5 directly as float and so on? 
Please help

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! You can use the `dtype` parameter in `pd.read_csv`. Fro the docs: "dtypeType name or dict of column -> type, optional"

Comment: You have taken dataframe values and did transpose to a single list. `.values.T[0].tolist()`. Dataframe can't hold multiple dtypes in a single column. If it is multiple columns specifying every column dtype would works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments. I'll try using these suggestions.